# How to put scrollbar in a table layout

Tags: android, scroll, android-tablelayout

I made a program and I made use of table layout as my layout,I want to put scrollbar int it, I used **table.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);** but I did not work,what is my best remedy? 
Here are my codes:

```
 TableLayout table = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
            table.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);// i used this but it did not work
            table.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);


            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());             

            TextView txt = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt2 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt3 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt4 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt5 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt6 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());

            tableRow.addView(txt);
            tableRow.addView(txt2);
            tableRow.addView(txt3);
            tableRow.addView(txt4);
            tableRow.addView(txt5);
            tableRow.addView(txt6);



            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            txt.setText("Question  ");
            txt2.setText("Excellent   ");
            txt3.setText("Best     ");
            txt4.setText("Better   ");
            txt5.setText("Good     ");
            txt6.setText("Poor     ");

            txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


            table.addView(tableRow);

            int j=0;
            for(j = 1; j<=count; j++){
                Random rnd = new Random(); 
                int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)); 


                tableRow = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());
                TextView name = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
                EditText et2 = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                EditText et3 = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                EditText et4 = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                EditText et5 = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                EditText et6 = new EditText (getApplicationContext());



                et2.setBackgroundColor(color);
                et3.setBackgroundColor(color);
                et4.setBackgroundColor(color);
                et5.setBackgroundColor(color);
                et6.setBackgroundColor(color);

                name.setText("Q#"+Integer.toString(j));





                tableRow.addView(name);
                tableRow.addView(et2);
                tableRow.addView(et3);
                tableRow.addView(et4);
                tableRow.addView(et5);
                tableRow.addView(et6);
                table.addView(tableRow);

            }
            TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());

            Button showtable = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            tableRow1.addView(showtable);
            showtable.setText("Show Table");
            showtable.setTextSize(8);

            table.addView(tableRow1);



            setContentView(table);
```

Comment: Use your TableLayout inside a ScrollView.

Comment: How about using `GridView`, it will handle most of scrolling functionality for you. Hope this will help http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: what you are looking for- `tableLayout inside scrollView` OR `scrollView inside Tablerow or table cell` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may create it as below:

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(context);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

table.addView(tableRow1);
scroll.addView(table);
   setContentView(scroll);
```

Comment: @GrlsHu can you help me again? i have my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926797/edittext-copy-values..

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a `ScrollView`.  You can set

```
android:scrollbars="@null"
```

in the XML resource and in that way the scrollbar will be not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use xml to design your layout as tablelayout...ScrollView must have a linear layout as a child layout of scrollview..and inside the linear layout is your table layout...

Answer (score 0):

Add a **ScrollView** Tag in XML and add **TableLayout** inside of it then all table will scroll by using it.